# stress tensor in Kazama-Suzuki construction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

This is a technical question about equation (2.42) of the original paper [[KS]](http://ccdb5fs.kek.jp/cgi-bin/img/allpdf?198810152) of the Kazama-Suzuki construction. I think the authors did a simple substitution $\tilde{J}^a=\hat{J}^a-\frac{i}{k}f_{a\bar{b}\bar{c}}j^{\bar{b}} j^{\bar{c}}$ in the equation (2.40) to get the equation (2.42). If this is the case, I think I will get plus signs for the last two terms of the equation (2.42). But in the paper these two terms have minus signs in front of them. I guess I have missed some important steps in the derivation, so any instruction/comment will be very helpful to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Excuse me, what is the precise question? Checking + or - sign?

Comment: Do you think it may be a matter of the conventions of Lie algebra: such as the conventions of $[T_a,T_b]=i f_{ab}{}^c T_c$ or $[T_a,T_b]= f_{ab}{}^c T_c$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, my question is why the signs are plus or minus. I think I followed the author's convention, with the $``i"$ as in their equation (2.1), which leads me to this confusion about the signs.